# Users as admins of multiple pages in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic

I need your help!

So I have a "users" and a "pages" table in my mysql database. I created a column in the "pages" table named "owner", where the username of the person who can edit that page goes. (I'll work on that thing later on, now it just displays a line of text)
So I've created a user with the username "Giannina" who is administrator of the home page and the info page. Then I coded this if-statement, that echoes out "you are admin of this page" when **any** user is logged in and on the home- or info page.

This is the code that does that.

```
if ($path['call_parts'][0] == "home" OR "info") { echo 'You are admin of this page'; }
```

So basically what I want to do is grab the *slugs* (which in this case are *home* and *info*) where $_SESSION['user_name'] (Giannina) is the same as the "owner" of the page, and spit them out in the code above.
This is the code I have so far:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE owner = '$_SESSION[user_name]'";
            $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

            while ($page_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                $var .= $page_info['slug'] .' OR '; 

            }

            echo chop($var, " OR ");
```

So what this does is, it grabs the two slugs that I've stored in the variable $page_info and spits them out like this:

```
home OR info
```

But i don't know where to go from there.

So to make it short I just need help with replacing the the line **"home" OR "info"** (in the first line of code) dynamically.

Any ideas and help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You might want something like this if I understand the question:

```
$pages= [];
while ($page_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $pages[] = $page_info['slug']; 
}
```

and

```
if (in_array($path['call_parts'][0], $pages, true)) { echo 'You are admin of this page'; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you have no idea for how long I struggled with this!

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$foo == 'bar' or 'baz'
```

is going to execute as

```
$foo == ('bar' or 'baz')
$foo == true
```

You cannot do multi-value comparisons like that. It would have to be

```
($foo == 'baz') OR ($foo == 'baz')
```

and if you have a bunch of values to test again, you can do

```
in_array($foo, array('bar', 'baz', .....))
```

instead